# Разделить слова в Memo Delphi XE

Tags: delphi

**В memo1 есть текст такого плана:**

Zadacha378328328

Zadacha435455656

Zadacha7785343434

Разделить текст по символам, то есть:

**К примеру:**

Указываю в Edit1 - число 4 (от которого символа делить)

Указываю в Edit2 разделитель, к примеру "-"

Указываю в Edit3 сколько частей в строке, к примеру 2

**И текст в memo1 изменяется:**

Zada-ch-a3-78-32-83-28

Zada-ch-a4-35-45-56-56

Zada-ch-a7-78-53-43-434 (если количество символов не парное то в конце вот так, все что осталось).

Comment: Учебные задания допустимы в качестве вопросов только при условии, что вы пытались решить их самостоятельно перед тем, как задать вопрос. Пожалуйста, **отредактируйте вопрос** и **укажите, что именно вызвало у вас трудности** при решении задачи. Например, приведите код, который вы написали, пытаясь решить задачу

Answer (score 1):

Задачу решила вот таким способом:

```
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var i: integer;
    L: TStringList;
    s: String;
begin
 L := TStringList.Create;
 L.Delimiter := Edit2.Text[1];
 for i := 0 to Memo1.Lines.Count - 1 do
  begin
   L.Clear;
   s := Memo1.Lines[i];
   L.Add(Copy(s, 1, StrToInt(Edit1.Text)));
   Delete(s, 1, StrToInt(Edit1.Text));
   while Length(s) > StrToInt(Edit3.Text) do
    begin
     L.Add(Copy(s, 1, StrToInt(Edit3.Text)));
     Delete(s, 1, StrToInt(Edit3.Text));
    end;
   L.Add(s);
   Memo2.Lines.Add(L.DelimitedText);
  end;
 L.Free;
end;
```

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте подойти просто - перебирайте входную строку по одному символу и добавляйте символ(ы) к результирующей строке (разумеется будет служебная переменная, в которой будет хранится число символов после последнего разделителя).

i-й символ строки S будет S[i].